# prove that the quadrilaterals are congruent

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

> If 2 quadrilaterals ABCD and PQRS have angles A,B,C,D equal to angles P, Q, R, S respectively and AB=PQ and CD=RS and is AD is not parallel to BC prove that the quadrilaterals are congruent.

I was solving an exercise on the congruence of triangles and I came across this question. Proving the triangles formed by the diagonals to be congruent is certainly not enough but that is all I can think of. What is the condition necessary for two quadrilaterals to be congruent?

Comment: See if this link is helpful : http://www.mcs.uvawise.edu/msh3e/resources/geometryBook/12Quadrilaterals.pdf

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг This link directly states some congruence conditions but I need a proof based on the congruence of triangles.

Comment: Aren't the proofs given in the latter part of the document?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I didn't see that. Thanks! But in this question is there any other simpler way to solve this because here I can't simply apply this congruence, I would have to prove it first...

Comment: No, I would think it is difficult to apply it. It is a difficult problem, because of the assmuption on the non-parallellity of $AB$ and $CD$, which doesn't seemingly have anything to do with congruence.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I am not able to figure out which condition satisfies the condtition given in this question...it seems to be the 5th one but that is marked as invalid

Comment: I don't know either. I just know this document from before, so  I thought I will show it to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will show that all side lengths are equal

Notation : Line segment $xy=[xy]$ Length of $[xy]=|xy|$

Note that $$ \angle DAB +\angle ABC +\angle ADC +\angle BCD =2\pi $$
so that we have three case :

(1) $\angle DAB +\angle ABC =\pi$ : So $AD\parallel BC$ So
it is a contradiction

(2) $ \angle DAB +\angle ABC <\pi $ : There is $X$ s.t. $$ D\in
[AX],\ C\in [BX]$$

For $PQRS$ we have $Y$ which is corresponded to $X$

Note that $\triangle XCD$ is congruent to $\triangle YRS$ by **SAA**-condition (side-angle-anlge - condition)

In further $\triangle XAB$ is congruent to $ \triangle YPQ$ by $SAA$
So $$ |AD|=|AX|-|DX|=|PY|-|SY|=|PS| $$

That is we can show that $|BC|=|QR|$

(3) $ \angle DAB +\angle ABC >\pi $ : This case is completely same
to case (2) So we complete the proof